# Как у потомка убрать внешние отступы родителя?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

Есть слайдер .gallery-slider сделанный с помощью owl-carousel. Этот слайдер заключен в блоке-обертке .wrapper c соответствующими отступами, но для того, чтобы мне добиться результата, как в макете, мне нужно чтобы слайды выходили за пределы блока .wrapper

Вот как должно получится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать и в начале я пробовал делать слайдер вне блока .wrapper, но это не подходящий способ, так как появились проблемы с позиционированием навигации и не только и поэтому занести слайдер в блок-обертку было самое действующее решение. Как сделать так, чтобы слайдеры вышли за пределы блока .wrapper?

**PS То что слайды наслаиваются друг на друга и на прочие некрасивые вещи не обращайте внимание, мне главное вытащить слайды за пределы**

Сам сайт cb95142.tmweb.ru
Весь код https://jsfiddle.net/sfv40Lwc/

```css
.gallery-slider {
  transform: translateY(-310px);
  max-height: 480px !important;
}
.gallery-slider .gal-slide img {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-height {
  min-height: 800px ;
  height: 100% ;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-item {
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-top: 440px;
  transition: 1s;
  min-width: 350px;
  min-height: 350px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-item.center {
  outline: 3px solid red;
  height: 700px !important;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 1s;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-item.center img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-slider owl-carousel">
                    
                    <div class="gal-slide">
                        <img src="img/gal-1.jpg" alt="1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="gal-slide">
                        <img src="img/gal-2.jpg" alt="2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="gal-slide">
                        <img src="img/gal-3.jpg" alt="3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="gal-slide">
                        <img src="img/gal-4.jpg" alt="4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="gal-slide">
                        <img src="img/gal-5.jpg" alt="4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="gal-slide">
                        <img src="img/gal-6.jpg" alt="4">
                    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Отрицательный `margin` у блока слайдера справа и слева

Comment: не помогло, просто блок смещается в сторону

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fLvckdyh/ вот пример, где несмотря на `padding` родителя, дочерний элемент выходит за его пределы. Я много раз это делал со слайдером `swiper`. Мб проблема именно в Вашем слайдере, почитайте документацию.
Мб под блоком слайдера Вы подумали, о блоке слайда. Я же имел ввиду весь контейнер слайдера.